# Custom user data in access token with ASOS

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib

I'm trying to impement the OpenID Connect server using `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server`.

Is it possible to place some custom user data to the access token when issuing token at authorization Server and then retrieve it at Resource Server during token validation and request processing?

**Example:** I want to write to the access token an IP address that was used to get token by user. Then at the resource server I want to compare current user IP address and IP address from token during token validation.

**Another example:** I want to write user's roles to token and then retrieve them in WebApi action filter or action itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider simply storing the IP address as a claim:

```
identity.AddClaim("ip_addr", HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
    OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);
```

Then, in your API controller, retrieve it using:

```
var address = User.FindFirst("ip_addr").Value;
```